# Devise Not Validating Password/Password Confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a custom controller that handles the editing of user passwords based off of the code [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password).

**User Model**

```
attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation, :username, :login
...
devise :database_authenticatable, 
       :lockable, 
       :registerable, 
       :recoverable, 
       :rememberable, 
       :trackable
```

**PasswordsController**

```
expose(:user) { current_user }

def update
  if user.update_with_password(params[:user])
    sign_in(user, :bypass => true)
    flash[:notice] = "success"
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

My edit password form is located [here](https://github.com/kyledecot/skateparks-web/blob/master/app/views/passwords/edit.html.erb).

The problem is that no matter what I enter (or don't enter for that matter) into the edit password form, The "success" flash method is displayed.

Comment: Does it all work how it should though? if the confirmation field doesn't match or current_password is wrong, it does not change the password?

Comment: It still changes it to whatever is in :password regardless of what (if anything) is in :password_confirmation.

Comment: what happens if you change the if statement to `if params[:user][:password] == params[:user][:password_confirmation]` and put `user.update_with_password(params[:user])` in the body?

Comment: You missing the `validatable` module or you just omit it from the code you provided?

Comment: Note that even if you included `validatable`, if you followed the [Devise and OmniAuth RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised?view=asciicast) instructions that include overriding `password_required?`, users who sign up through omniauth will not get their password resets confirmed.

Comment: @gmcnaughton Thanks for mentioning this! Saved me a few hours. :)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you want Devise to do validations, you need to add the `:validatable` module to your model. This is fairly easy to do, just add `:validatable` to the list of module in the `devise` call, so your model says:

```
devise
   :database_authenticatable, 
   :lockable, 
   :registerable, 
   :recoverable, 
   :rememberable, 
   :trackable,
   :validatable
```

This will make devise add validations.

Another easy way is to add your own validations. If you just want to validate that the password confirmation matches, you can add a `validates_confirmation_of` validation by adding this to your model:

```
validates_confirmation_of :password
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `validates_confirmation_of :password` was what I was missing

Answer (score 6):

I think you forgot to initialize strong parameter in application_controller.rb in rails 4

before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
 protected

```
 def configure_permitted_parameters    
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up){|u|u.permit(:email,:password,:password_confirmation)}
 end
```

Comment: That's what bit me, I forgot to add `password_confirmation` to the list of sanitized parameters, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

find your object for updation in controller.

```
user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    unless user.blank?
      if user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        flash[:notice] = "User updated successfully."
        redirect_to "somwhere"
      else
        render :action => 'edit'
      end
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
```

if you  don't want to update the old password then add these line before updation so the new code will be:

```
    user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
        unless user.blank?
          params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
          params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
if user.update_attributes(params[:user])
            flash[:notice] = "User updated successfully."
            redirect_to "somwhere"
          else
            render :action => 'edit'
          end
        else
          render :action => 'edit'
        end
```

write somthing like this in user.rb model

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :locakable
```